# Http status 400 -The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect. Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I spent a lot of time on this problem, but can`t resolve it. Please Help!  When I submit form from JSP I get this error.
My code:

```
<form  action="/albums/add" method="post">
<%--<div><input type="file"></div>--%>
<div>Name: <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name"></div>
<div>Year: <input type="text" name="year" placeholder="Release year"></div>
<div>
    <select name="singer" id="singer">
    <c:forEach items="${singers}" var="s">
        <option value="${s.id}">${s.name}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
</div>
<input type="submit" >
```

And my controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String albumsGET(ModelMap map) {
    List<Album> albums = albumDAO.getAllAlbums();
    map.addAttribute("albums", albums);
    return "forward:/Albums.jsp";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String albumsAddGET(ModelMap map) {
    map.put("singers", singerDAO.getAllSingers());
    return "forward:/WEB-INF/Pages/Album/AddAlbum.jsp";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String albumsPOST(@ModelAttribute Album album, HttpServletRequest req) {

        Singer s = singerDAO.getSingerById(Long.valueOf(req.getParameter("singer")));
        s.getAlbumList().add(album);
        album.setSinger(s);
        singerDAO.updateSinger(s);
    return "redirect:/albums";
}
```

}

Comment: Check for your `Album` and `Singer` entity, if it is properly matched with the form.

Answer (score 1):

You can throw custom exception provided by spring, create class with **@ControllerAdvice** annotation and throws custom exception with different HTTP status code

Answer (score 0):

That is parameter mapping error for @ModelAttribute which HTTP return code 400.

There are some reasons that rises this error.

1. There is no parameter name for your `Album` Object.
2. There are `NULL` value for mapping `Album` Obejct.

So, if you can check item `${singers}`, you  should check substituted properly value.

Next, in `Album` Object, you should check getter/setter method.

I could have resolved that issue to setting default values for `Object` (etc. VO)